# Installing Node alongside Flask

Tags: python, node.js, npm

I'm currently starting a fresh Web Development Project and were planning on going down my fairly standard route of using Flask for my back end.

For the first time, I have considered the usage of Babel as I want to begin writing my client side code in ES6 whilst still allowing my code to be used on the majority of current browsers. TypeScript has also been suggested as an alternative (I am aware that TypeScript and Babel set out to do somewhat different things).

Both of these require installation via npm, which my research seems to indicate is a fairly sensible thing, and npm requires Node. My question is, is there anything weird or wonderful I should bear in mind when using Node just to have npm installed for package management?

As further background, the VM is running Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at all weird to do this. npm is package management FOR Node. How is Babel run? It is run with Node. Babel, while it may seem like a standalone tool, is just a node script, see Babel's source [here](https://github.com/babel/babel). If you need Babel, by all means install Node to run it.

Comment: Ah I see. I'm a relative newb to back end bits hence the foolish question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It just feels weird using Node to manage Javascript libraries for Python, though :/

Comment: Ehh, it's weird sometimes yeah. Personally I've just made peace with the fact that every app I build that has a browser based client side will need Node/npm. Technically, it isn't for the Python itself, it's for client side preprocessing and bundling etc. Frontend dev is a whole different animal